# Add fontFamily object to theme.json

Tags: fonts, full-site-editing, theme.json

I have an FSE-related question

- I'm trying to add a font to the 2023 theme but it's not showing in Gutenberg editor.
- In theme.json, in the "settings.typography.fontFamilies" section, I added the following fontFamily definition:

```json
{
    "fontFamily": "Sarabun, sans-serif",
    "name": "Sarabun",
    "slug": "sarabun"
},
```

I realize that this doesn't import the actual font definition files (...woff2), but I think it should at least show "Sarabun" as an option in gutenberg when I edit a Paragraph block and select the "Typography > Font" dropdown.

Note - this *does* work when I do these steps on the 2022 theme.

QUESTION - Does anyone know why the font (eg "Sarabun") wouldn't be showing?

Comment: did you set your site to dev mode? `theme.json` gets cached for performance reasons so if you're not telling your WP install it's a dev or local environment it'll assume it's a production env and cache `theme.json` and ignore your changes. Also have you tried declaring the files to use?

Comment: no I don't have it in dev mode - ie in wp-config.php I have "define( 'WP_DEBUG', false );".  I'm not sure what you mean by "declaring the files to use" - Can you please explain that a bit more?  Although, when I switch to the 2022 theme I *do* see the new font in the "Typography > Font" dropdown.

Comment: most likely because it's re-reading `theme.json` when you switch. `WP_DEBUG` is an ancient debugging constant, but a few major releases ago a new constant was added to `wp-config.php` that lets you hint to WordPress what kind of environment it's on, e.g. a local env, dev env, staging, production and WordPress will behave slightly differently depending on how it's set. By default it assumes it's a production site. It will even set `WP_DEBUG` for you if you say it's a dev environment: https://developer.wordpress.org/advanced-administration/wordpress/wp-config/#wp-environment-type

Comment: as for declaring what files to use, "I realize that this doesn't import the actual font definition files (...woff2), " I meant doing exactly that, declaring in `theme.json` the files you intend to use. Note though that you should not be modifying 2022 or 2023, you're meant to create child themes so that your changes aren't destroyed when those themes get updated and your modifications remain separate. Last thing you want is to have to redo them all again because you want features and changes in an updated version of the original like form blocks

Comment: Also if you did declare the font files, WP would conditionally load and enqueue them automatically when they're used, and it'd use the font loader work that's been done in gutenberg so it was always the current state of the art, better than a naive import in CSS. WP would also automatically add it to the upcoming font library, import it correctly in the editor, and display it

Answer (score 0):

@TomJNowell - Thanks for this detail info, clarification and advice.  I didn't know about the new debug constant so will learn how to utilize that, and will use a child theme.

I wasn't able to fix this issue, so I spun up a new server and my font updates worked.  So I'll just abandon the original server. I'm learning the full site editor and wp theme development so I don't have to keep that old server.

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see my font.
but when I rename the folder of Theme TT4, suddenly every font shows up in Gutenberg editor !!
what is the reason? and should I rename a folder or make a child theme?

after this, I renamed it back to the original name, but same issue, could not see the font.
what is the reason behind it?